# Test suite failed to run Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to replace Karma with Jest, for some existing unit tests, in my angular project. I managed to have all configured just that when running one particular test i get this error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import createFind from './_createFind.js';

Syntax error: Unexpected identifier
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/angular2-jsonapi/src/models/json-api.model.ts:1:1)`
```

this is how my package.json looks like:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./setupJest.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./node_modules",
      "./dist/",
      "./src/test.ts"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "./node_modules/(?!lodash-es/)"
    ],
    "modulePaths": ["src/app"],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$",
        "astTransformers": [
          "./node_modules/jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer"
        ],
        "diagnostics": false
      }
    }
  },
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
"env": {
    "development": {
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    },
    "test": {
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
}
```

}

**#Update1**

In the meantime I understand that is actually a problem with the angular2-jsonapi module as it states here: https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi/issues/209

So I thought that I could mock this module, by creating 
 '**mocks**'

folder and an angular2-jsonapi.js file in it; the code being:

```
export class JsonApiModel {}
```

but now the error states something like: 
[image]

I also tried code like:

```
const jsonapi = require('angular2-jsonapi');
jest.genMockFromModule('angular2-jsonapi');
module.exports=jsonapi;
```

in **mocks**/angular2-jsonapi.js file

How could I mock an entire node module ?

Comment: Can you include the bad test case?

Comment: well, it is not about a test case. it's the entire test class that it is failing; I am only initializing  a component class and configureTestingModule with testBed in the describe part.

Comment: This is likely a problem with your babel config. You are probably using some es2015 or later syntax that jest can't understand. Make sure to use babel to preprocess any js code before running it.

Comment: indeed is es2015 and angular 7; i also attached my babel config file...